# Consolidating multiple OR and AND conditions in R

Tags: r, logical-operators, logical-or, logical-and

I want to consolidate multiple OR and AND conditions in R. I think `x1 == 1 | x1 == 2` can be consolidated as `x1 %in% c(1, 2)`. I'm wondering how `x1 == 1 | y1 == 1` and `x1 == 1 & y1 == 1` can be consolidated into more compact `R` code.

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
y1 <- c(1, 2, 4)

x1 == 1 | x1 == 2
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
x1 %in% c(1, 2)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

x1 == 1 | y1 == 1
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

intersect(x1, y1) == 1
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
intersect(x1, y1) == 2
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE

intersect(x1, y1) %in% c(1, 2)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE

> x1 == 1 & y1 == 1
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**Edited**

The code `(x1 == 1 | x1 == 2) & (y1 == 1 | y1 == 2)` is equal to `Reduce(any, lapply(list(x1),` %in%`, c(1, 2)))  & Reduce(any, lapply(list(y1),` %in%`, c(1, 2)))`.  Wondering to write this in more compact way.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans for your comment. The output of `x1 == 1 & y1 == 1` is `TRUE FALSE FALSE` whereas `all(c(x1, y1) == 1)` gives the output `FALSE`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, it was a fly-by comment, not helpful.

Comment: I can't think of anything that is either code-golf-better or faster than these primitive operations.

Comment: are your vectors integers? ie `x1*y1 == 1`

Comment: Be careful if `NA` occur, `c(1, NA, 4) == 1 | c(1, NA, 4) == 2` is different from `c(1, NA, 4) %in% c(1, 2)`. `\`%in%\`` is more related to `?match` than to `\`==\``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need `lapply()` and `Reduce()` for a clean "hackless" abstraction:

```r
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
y1 <- c(1, 2, 4)
y1 == 1 | x1 == 1
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
Reduce(`|`, lapply(list(x1, y1), `==`, 1))
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

You can win a few characters with `apply(cbind(x1, y1) == 1, 1, all)` (using matrix as an intermediate shape) but I don't know if it's worth it.

<sup>Created on 2024-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for very useful answer. Would appreciate it if you guide how to write this `(x1 == 1 | x1 == 2) & (y1 == 1 | y1 == 2)` in more compact way. I tried this one `Reduce(`|`, lapply(list(x1), `%in%`, c(1, 2)))  & Reduce(`|`, lapply(list(y1), `%in%`, c(1, 2)))` but it is too long.

Comment: In this case I guess it would be ``Reduce(`&`, lapply(list(x1, y1), `%in%`, c(1,2))``

Comment: But as fun as this is as a programming challenge, it seems like you have data that should be structured differently and you might reconsider your code upstream, maybe you have vectors that should be in a data frame, long rather than wide. If `x1` and `y1` are the same kind of things, with tidy data they would probably be in the same column on top of each other

Comment: I also assumed that you have more vectors than just 2 in your real case, if not please use the readable simple options! :D

Comment: FYI I added some benchmarks to my answer. This is definitely the winner.

Answer (score 11):

#### Create some data

As `x1 == 1 | y1 == 1` doesn't seem too verbose, let's create more vectors:

```r
set.seed(1)
lapply(1:10, \(.) sample(10, 10, replace = TRUE)) |>
    setNames(paste0(c("x", "y"), c(1:5, 1:5))) |>
    list2env(.GlobalEnv)
ls()
#  [1] "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4" "x5" "y1" "y2" "y3" "y4" "y5"
```

Now it does become quite tedious to write:

```r
x1 == 1 | y2 == 1 | x3 == 1 | y4 == 1 | x5 == 1 | y1 == 1 | x2 == 1 | y3 == 1 | x4 == 1 | y5 == 1 
#  [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

#### Use a data frame

We're using element-wise logical operators, so the vectors are guaranteed to be the same length. Let's put them into a data frame to perform the comparison:

```r
compare <- function(..., val = 1, op = c("==", "<", ">", ">=", "<=", "!=")) {
    fun <- match.fun(match.arg(op))
    rowSums(fun(data.frame(...), val)) > 0
}
```

We can then do:

```r
compare(x1, y2, x3, y4, x5, y1, x2, y3, x4, y5)
#  [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Or alternatively if this is still too much typing, we can put the vectors in list (which is better anyway), and supply that to the function:

```r
# Create a list of x1:x5 and y1:y5
l  <- mget(ls(pattern = "[xy]\\d"))
compare(l)
#  [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

#### Some tests

This works with `==` and other operators as well.

```r
identical(
    compare(l, val = 1),
    x1 == 1 | y2 == 1 | x3 == 1 | y4 == 1 | x5 == 1 | y1 == 1 | x2 == 1 | y3 == 1 | x4 == 1 | y5 == 1
)
# [1] TRUE

identical(
    compare(l, op = ">", val = 9),
    x1 > 9 | y2 > 9 | x3 > 9 | y4 > 9 | x5 > 9 | y1 > 9 | x2 > 9 | y3 > 9 | x4 > 9 | y5 > 9
)
# [1] TRUE
```

#### Performance

An advantage of using a data frame (rather than, say, a matrix) is that it is just a list of pointers to each vector. This means no copies of the data are made. Additionally, data frames support element-wise comparison operations. As [Jenny Bryan said](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows-in-r-with-the-tidyverse?slide=16), *Of course, someone has to write loops. It doesn’t have to be you.*

#### A note on coercion and copies

It has been pointed out in the comments that `rowSums(dat)`, where `dat` is a `data.frame`, will coerce `dat` to a matrix i.e. make a copy.

This is true (and interesting!) but the input data is not copied in this case. The above code does not call `rowSums(data.frame(...))`, which would trigger coercion to a matrix. It runs `rowSums(data.frame(...)==val)`. We can see an equivalent difference by using the debug browser:

```r
debug(as.matrix)
rowSums(mtcars) # Triggers debug browser; debugging in: as.matrix(x)
rowSums(mtcars == 1) # Does not trigger browser
```

This is because `mtcars==1` is already a matrix. Now, if you dig into the [`Ops.data.frame()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/9ba15634fcbf5570d8c931d8be43f66dde98579c/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L1606) source, which is the function that is called when you use `==` on a data frame, you may see that it calls `matrix(value, nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn,cn))`. However, `matrix()` is called on the return value to ensure that `mtcars==1` returns a matrix, and not on `mtcars` (or whatever the input data is) which is not copied.

#### Some benchmarks

Here are some benchmarks for the three approaches:

1. `reduce`: The `Reduce()` approach by [moodymudskipper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78226974/12545041).
2. `df`: The `compare()` function which uses a data frame.
3. `cbind_mat`; The `%==.|% <- function(x, y) apply(t(x) == y, 2, any)` function defined in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78211271/12545041) from G. Grothendieck.

I varied both the number of vectors and length of vectors from 10 to 10k elements. The actual picture about whether a data frame or matrix is better is complicated. For shorter vectors, using a matrix is much quicker than a data frame. For longer vectors, a data frame is considerably quicker than a matrix, with much less memory allocation.

What is unequivocally clear is that `Reduce()` is the quickest option:

[image]

Similarly, as the data gets larger, the data frame approach uses a lot less RAM than coercing the vectors to matrices. However, the `Reduce()` approach uses the least RAM in all cases.

[image]

##### Benchmark and plot code

```r
results <- bench::press(
    num_vectors = 10^(1:4),
    vec_length = 10^(1:4),
    {
        l <- lapply(seq(num_vectors), \(.) sample(vec_length, vec_length, replace = TRUE))
        bench::mark(
            min_iterations = 10,
            max_iterations = 1000,
            relative = TRUE,
            df = {
                compare(l)
            },
            cbind_mat = {
                do.call(cbind, l) %==.|% 1
            },
            reduce = {
                Reduce(`|`, lapply(l, `==`, 1))
            }
        )
    }
)

# Plots

library(ggplot2)

# beeswarm plot
autoplot(results) +
    ggh4x::facet_grid2(
        vars(num_vectors), vars(vec_length),
        scales = "free_x", independent = "x",
        labeller = label_both
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous() +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 13) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")

# RAM usage plot
results |>
    dplyr::mutate(
        expr = attr(expression, "description"),
        mem_alloc = unclass(mem_alloc),
        size = as.factor(num_vectors)
    ) |>
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(
        x = reorder(expr, mem_alloc),
        y = mem_alloc,
        fill = expr
    ), color = "black") +
    ggh4x::facet_grid2(
        vars(num_vectors), vars(vec_length),
        scales = "free", independent = "y"
    ) +
    labs(
        title = "Total RAM usage",
        y = "Relative RAM usage",
        x = "Expression"
    ) +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: Beware on what you said re: the advantage of using a data.frame. In your solution you used `rowSums`, which can be applied to a data.frame, but under the hood coerces it to a matrix. So a copy is actually made.

Comment: @nicola interesting, I didn't know that. I don't think it's an issue here though. The code is basically doing `rowSums(data.frame(l) == 1)` rather than `rowSums(data.frame(l)) == 1`. So the argument to `rowSums()` is `data.frame(l) == 1`, which is already a matrix, rather than the original data frame, so it shouldn't make a copy. I didn't know that happened under the hood of `rowSums()` though - I tend to assume functions like that are optimised in C. Something to watch out for - thanks.

Comment: @SamR since data frames are all about columns, it's a good assumption that anything that works on rows of a data frame converts it to a matrix. `rowSums`, `rowMeans`, `apply`, ... well I can't actually think of any others.

Comment: @SamR Still, your point regarding performance advantages of using a data.frame here is very dubious. Don't know if you are suggesting that using `cbind`(which will create a matrix) instead of `data.frame` will make copies somewhere. I think that a matrix would have been more efficient; look at the source code you posted how much checking, subsetting and coersions are made to use logical operators between data.frames. Those operators work faster with numeric vectors for sure.

Comment: @nicola I added some benchmarks to my answer. I was hoping they'd unequivocally prove my point but the picture is a bit more complicated. If the vectors are short then matrices are better. As they get longer a data frame is better. I'm sure this is because copies are made when you coerce to a matrix - because a matrix is memory contiguous they have to be. This isn't the case with a data frame. This is somewhat moot anyway though as the `Reduce()` approach blows them both out the water.

Comment: @SamR Maybe my point wasn't clear. You can have the same results if in your `compare` function you use `cbind(...)` instead of `data.frame(...)`. The other solution you benchmarked is different in many points to yours. My point is that there is not any performance advantage of using at a some point a data.frame just for the sake of it.

Comment: Just to be clear: what you benchmarked has an `apply` and a `t` call that are completely unnecessary.

Comment: More concretely: test `compare <- function(l, val = 1, op = c("==", "<", ">", ">=", "<=", "!=")) {
    fun <- match.fun(match.arg(op))
    rowSums(fun(data.frame(l), val)) > 0
}` against `compare_1 <- function(l, val = 1, op = c("==", "<", ">", ">=", "<=", "!=")) {
    fun <- match.fun(match.arg(op))
    rowSums(fun(do.call(cbind, l), val)) > 0
}` and you'll see that compare_1 wins across the board.

Answer (score 6):

**1)** The following checks that x1[i] and y1[i] are both 1, i.e. AND.

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 1)
y1 <- c(1, 2, 4, 3)

paste(x1, y1) == "1 1"
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

**2)** If we knew that the vectors are composed of integers >= 1, as in the question, then we can use pmin and pmax.  Note that they have optional na.rm= arguments which can be set to handle NAs.

```
pmin(x1, y1) == 1        # OR
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE

pmax(x1, y1) == 1        # AND
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

All of the above readily generalize to more than 2 vectors.

**3)** The expression in the question involving just x1 can be shortened slightly

```
x1 %in% 1:2
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

**4)** We can regard the case with x1 and y1 as a generalized matrix multiplication where * is replaced with == and + is replaced with either | or & .  In the APL language this is =.v and =.^ .  (See https://rpubs.com/deleeuw/158476 and blockmodeling::genMatrixMult for other implementations.)

```
`%==.|%` <- function(x, y) apply(t(x) == y, 2, any)
`%==.&%` <- function(x, y) apply(t(x) == y, 2, all)

cbind(x1, y1) %==.&% c(1, 1)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

cbind(x1, y1) %==.|% c(1, 1)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I the idea of defining infix operators but if the data is reasonably sized I think `cbind.data.frame(x1, y1)` is better as it won't copy the data.

Comment: In R matrix multiplication is done on matrices and not on data frames so if  you want to keep the analogy  the input needs to be a matrix.

Comment: I'm missing your point - maybe because I don't know APL. Are you saying that there are cases where `cbind(x1, y1) %==.&% c(1, 1)` will give different output to `data.frame(x1, y1)  %==.&% c(1, 1)`? Or are you saying it's better to use a matrix because of the conceptual similarity to matrix multiplication? Or both?

Comment: Try `BOD %*% 1:2`  where BOD is a built-in data frame  You get an error because a data frame cannot be an argument to matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generalization based on the answers by [@moodymudskipper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78226974/12158757) and [@SamR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78210348/12158757)

```
f <- function(
    ...,
    val = 1,
    op = c("==", "<", ">", ">=", "<=", "!="),
    how = c("|", "&")) {
    Reduce(as.symbol(how), lapply(list(...), as.symbol(op), val))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the pieces together, and evaluate it as an expression, for example

```r
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
y1 <- c(1, 2, 4)
string <- paste0(c('x','y'), 1, '==', c(1,2), collapse='&')
eval(parse(text=string))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```